# update the prdouct to the database

Tags: html, flask

#i have managed to add something to the database, also i now want to update something in the database, which kinda works right now however it updates everything except from the name, and the name has to stay the same, i have 3 different files Server.py , ProductSearch.html and file for the database(the name for the table is Product)
Here are some screen shots:

Server.py

[cotains links to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99yM7.png)

ProductSearch.html

[this is the html file for the forms and the design of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlBT5.png)

[Still the same file, it has some pop ups and a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrMXJ.png)

[Still ProducSearch.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtE2r.png)

[That was the last one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhPVB.png)

Finally the Databse with the table:

[Pretty self explanatory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEluM.png)

Comment: You should do code snippets instead of pictures. How should we reproduce this? There is no time to typing all of this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SAhmed - Please edit your question to contain formatted text, not images (screenshots don't help, especially with code). This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. Also, please stop trying to move the conversation from Stack Overflow to an offsite chat tool. This isn't the place to do that. All content (questions, comments, answers) need to be here.